# Bootstrap 3 divs layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a project with Bootstrap 3 and I'd like to make a layout like you see in the picture:

[image: Layout]

Any thoughts on how to do this? Some code bits will be very appreciated.

Thanks

I'm currently trying out something like this:

```
       <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-3 features">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi esse reiciendis illo expedita voluptatibus consequatur culpa tempore labore eveniet voluptates, rerum, odio vitae quae, impedit et? Ea et culpa veniam?
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 features">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi esse reiciendis illo expedita voluptatibus consequatur culpa tempore labore eveniet voluptates, rerum, odio vitae quae, impedit et? Ea et culpa veniam?
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 features">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi esse reiciendis illo expedita voluptatibus consequatur culpa tempore labore eveniet voluptates, rerum, odio vitae quae, impedit et? Ea et culpa veniam?
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 features">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi esse reiciendis illo expedita voluptatibus consequatur culpa tempore labore eveniet voluptates, rerum, odio vitae quae, impedit et? Ea et culpa veniam?
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 iphone-bottom">
                    <img src="img/iphone-bottom.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Download Revolut">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 center-block download-btn">
                    <a href="#download" class="btn btn-get-it">
                        Get it
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: try the solution i posted. hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here : http://jsbin.com/lesud/1/edit?html,css,output

```
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="row colblue">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>text</div>
      </div>
       <div class="row colblue">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="black col-xs-8">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/400/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="row colblue">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>text</div>
      </div>
       <div class="row colblue">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><p>text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't thought of this kind of layout

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

### HTML

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="col-lg-12 bl-box">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 bl-box">
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col2 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col3 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="col-lg-12 bl-box">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 bl-box">
      </div> 
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .bl-box {
       margin:50px  0;
       background:blue;
       color:#fff;
    }

.col2 {
       padding:50px 0;
       background:#000;
       color:#fff;
    }
```

**Fiddle Link :** http://jsfiddle.net/vdyzZ/

Comment: you need to do some alignment from your side otherwise it works.